# When Multibranch pipeline when job is trigged, what is stored in Jenkins workspace?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am not sure if I am asking the question in right way.
When I am triggering the multi branch pipeline job and I do "checkout scm" in Jenkinsfile, does it checkout the pull request or Master + pull request?

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your settings.
As I remember, multibranch pipeline builds pull requests in separated view and it can build as PR source branch and result of PR. It cloned your repo, checkouts target branch, merges source branch into it and runs your stages.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the logs you will see that it checks out the hash of the commit

example: `git checkout 1fb651dfdcbea276627de0247bbf5047840cae4c`

As for workspace, if you log in to the Jenkins machine where this is running you will see that each branch has a separated workspace.  Here you will find the source code of the checked out branch.  The separated workspace ensures that there is no conflict when working with multiple concurrent branch builds.

Comment: Thanks! if I want to checkout the pull request branch with Master, what do i do?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to checkout master?